# How to read a String followed by an int in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream

I've been struggling to get this done. What I need is to read a input like this: `DEPOSITO 123 1000.00`, but the String "DEPOSITO" needs to be saved in one variable, the int "123" to another variable and the double "1000.00" to another variable. The problem is that I couldn't find anything like `scanner.nextString()`, if I could scan just the string into a variable, I probably could scan the rest of the input stream with `scanner.nextInt()` and `scanner.nextDouble()`. If I do `scanner.next()` on a attempt to read only the string, it reads the whole line, so what is the answer to my problem here? I'm really clueless.

Comment: Look into splitting the strings into 3 parts by space.

Comment: Could you post the part of the code that you're having trouble with? It would it make it easier for us to help you

Comment: @user3814613 Has answered it, but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the input always begins with a string, you could get the string first, and then determine how many variables there are after it based on that:

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();

// use regex to split string
String tokens = input.split("\\s+");

String firstPart = tokens[0];

int intPart = 0;
double doublePart = 0;
int transferenciaInt = 0;

if(firstPart.equals("SAQUE") || firstPart.equals("DEPOSITO"))
{
    intPart = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    doublePart = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
}
else
{
    intPart = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    transferenciaInt = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
    doublePart = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
}
```

For more information on regular expressions (regex) see this: [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: The input isn't always made of 3 parts, sometimes it has 4 parts. What determines that is the String at the start of the input, if it is "SAQUE" or "DEPOSITO" than it will have more 2 parts (int and double). However, if the string is "TRANSFERENCIA" than it has more 3 parts (int, int and double)

Comment: I can see the logic behind it, the problem is.. I'm debugging my program step by step and it reads the whole line as a String input, but when I do `String[] tokens = input.split("\\s+")` it doesn't split the string, i have access to the variables pannel and `tokens[0]` is the whole input.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] s = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Then you'll have 3 strings:

1. `s[0]` that'll return "DEPOSITO"
2. `s[1]` returns "123"
3. `s[2]` and it'll return "1000.00"

And now:

```
Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
Double d = Double.parseDouble(s[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can parse value like this

```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String array[] = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s");
    String strValue = array[0];
    int intValue = Integer.valueOf(array[array.length - 2]);
    int intValue1 = 0;
    double doubleValue = Double.valueOf(array[array.length - 1]);
    if ("TRANSFERENCIA".equalsIgnoreCase(strValue)) {
        intValue1 = Integer.valueOf(array[array.length - 3]);
    }
```